# FPC1020 + WeMos D1 Mini

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a [FPC1020am](http://www.shenzhen2u.com/FPC1020-Fingerprint-touch-sensor-kit) that work perfectly with arduino and a [ESP8266 D1 Mini V2 NodeMcu 4MB Lua](https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/391803724654?chn=ps&dispItem=1&adgroupid=41767405657&rlsatarget=pla-327666159789&abcId=1129006&adtype=pla&merchantid=7275934&poi=&googleloc=2826&device=c&campaignid=861364981&crdt=0) that can connect to server.

How can I connect the **FPC1020** direcetly to **ESP8266 D1 Mini** to scan finger and send matched id to server?

here is my code and error:

```
#include <NewSoftSerial.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <FPC1020.h>


extern unsigned char l_ucFPID;
extern unsigned char rBuf[192];  //Receive return data
#define sw_serial_rx_pin 2 //  Connect this pin to TX on the FPC1020
#define sw_serial_tx_pin 3 //  Connect this pin to RX on the FPC1020

const char* ssid = "-------";
const char* password = "-------";

const char* host = "-------";
String url = "-------?id=";

NewSoftSerial swSerial(sw_serial_rx_pin, sw_serial_tx_pin); // Fingerprint serial (RX, TX)
FPC1020 Finger(&swSerial);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  pinMode(4, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Please put your finger on the Sensor.");
  while(Serial.available()<=0);

  if( Finger.Search()){
    Serial.print("Success, your User ID is: "); 
    url = "-------?id=" + l_ucFPID;
    Serial.println( l_ucFPID, DEC);

    WiFiClient client;
    if (!client.connect(host, 80)) {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
      return;
    }

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                 "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

    String line = "";
    while (client.connected()) {
      line = client.readString();
    }

    Serial.println(line);    

  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Failed, please try again.");
  }
}
```

And the error is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\NewSoftSerial\NewSoftSerial.cpp:41:27: fatal error: avr/interrupt.h: No such file or directory

 #include <avr/interrupt.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board WeMos D1 R2 & mini.
```

Comment: We are not a free code writing service.

Comment: it's a serial device, hook it into the MCU's UART line, or use SoftwareSerail...

Comment: @dandavis the softwareSerial doesnt work on WeMos D1 Mini.. is there any other component that do this on WeMos D1 Mini?

Comment: i don't know where you got that idea, but i use SS all the time on d1minis...

Comment: @dandavis when i want to compile my code, I got this error: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @dandavis complete error:  fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

                            ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board WeMos D1 R2 & mini.

Comment: @mimskydo - That is user error, you haven't downloaded the Software Serial Library or you haven't placed it in the correct location.  Try reading the readme or IDE help on how to download 3rd party libraries.  This is why I said you should have included the error message when you asked this question on your other post, the problem would have been solved by now.

Comment: @CodeGorilla I update the question by adding code and error. Would u please take a look at it? I totally confused about it.. also I use "NewSoftSerial" instead of "SoftwareSerial" because of arduino website recomenation. tnx

Comment: [NewSoftSerial](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/newsoftserial/) is now in the Arduino core as SoftwareSerial. I doubt the old NewSoftSerial supports the ESP8266.

Comment: @mimskydo- avr = Arduino, so when you see avr in a path then it means it wants something just for the Arduino, not for the ESP.  You now need to find a version of software serial that works with the ESP.  OR you could add a hardware serial port http://www.nxp.com/products/signal-chain/bridges/single-uart-with-i2c-bus-spi-interface-64-bytes-of-transmit-and-receive-fifos-irda-sir-built-in-support:SC16IS740_750_760 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried this, but a D1 Mini has 2.5 serial ports.

- The Tx and Rx pins are Serial0.
- Digital pin 4 is TX1 - There appears to be no RX pin.
- D7 and D8 are Rx2 and Tx2.

So rather than using SoftwareSerial or NewSoftwareSerial try using Serial2.  It might work.